# How to Use multiple terminals on HPC for ROS

Tags: ros, slurm, hpc

I have to run a ROS simulation on a HPC. On my local PC I usually open multiple terminals to run different ros commands which function together like roscore,etc. Now I am not sure how to do this on an HPC, I need to submit a job file for it.

Answer (score 0):

For running multiple nodes ROS has roslaunch. You can bundle all the different nodes you want to run with different parameters  and it will take care of it.

Read more about it here: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch